# need to check input form if user upload the file or not with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have input form to upload you file and submitting that file(method = post) i need to cheack if user upload the image or not. if not should display error message and return false. but in my case return false don't working

my code

```
const jobs = document.getElementById("jobImage");
const error = document.getElementById("Error");
```

my function

```
function func(){
    if(jobs.value < 1){    
     console.log("1")
     error.style.display = "block";
     error.textContent = "Pleas upload your image";
     setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); },5000);
      return false
    }
        
}
```

when i use my function  its return true not false

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button  type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" id="save" onclick="func()"><a href="www.google.com">Go now</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

best regards

Comment: Why would you reload the page?

Comment: Well you do not cancel the click..... onclick="return func()">

Comment: thanks but i am already trying used your solution but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must change if to :

```
if( jobs.files.length == 0 ){
    ...
}
```

Comment: its working thank you